# What is the gamut and backlight for a MacBook pro retina display?

Tags: display-calibration, backlight, color-gamut, spyder3

I am using the Spyder4pro to calibrate my MacBook pro retina display and it asks what my display's gamut and backlight are.

Choices for gamut are: `Unknown`, `Normal`, and `Wide`.
Choices for backlight are: `Unknown`, `Fluorescent (CCFL)`, `White LED`, and `RGD LED`.

Which of these should I select to match my built in screen?

Comment: Well, seems like Unknown is what you have, given you do not know. The calibration is unlikely to be less accurate, just take longer to account for more possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Spyder's software is probably going to suck horribly, you should be using Dispcal GUI.

It's going to be sRGB (normal gamut) -- see post 5, here: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-Retina-2-3-GHz-Mid-2012.78959.0.html

Backlight is LED, third post here: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/190272/No+backlight+after+LCD+replacement

.. I don't know if it's RGB or white. I assume the latter, but I don't think dispcal will even ask between the two.

Comment: Dispcal wants to know the backlit for Spyder devices, it's important to know this for correct calibration. It won't ask you, there is a drop down where you have to select the right one or you get wrong calibration results.